# DIV Scroll working for one table but not working for another table

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, overflow

Can someone look this issue?

The scroll bar is showing for one table where as it's not showing for another table which is made of same CSS and present HTML file.

**For Top Table Scrollbar is not showing but for bottom table it's showing**
[image: For Top Table Scrollbar is not showing but for bottom table it's showing]

**HTML table not showing Scroll**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="professional">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Account Number</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0" >First Name</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Last Name</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Status</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Services</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Suspend Status</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Phone Number</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">Activation Code</th>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-show="accountInfo.accountId > 0">SSO ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.accountId}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.firstName}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.lastName}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.status}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.group}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.suspended}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.homePhone}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.activationCode}}</td>
          <td class="features" >{{accountInfo.guid}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**HTML Table showing Scroll**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="professional">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="tableheader" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">{{list.deviceType}}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">{{list.instanceId}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">{{list.firmwareVersion}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">{{list.manufacturer}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">{{list.model}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="features" ng-repeat="list in cellularIPAddressValue">
            {{list.troubles[0].description}}
            <p ng-show="list.troubles[0]">Failure On {{list.troubles[0].date}}
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 1350px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.professional .title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional .tableheader, .professional .pt-footer {
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional .tableheader:after {
    border-top-color: #2980b9;
}

.professional .pt-footer:after {
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: it seems the first table doesn't have enough data to scroll. You need more headers and content to see scroll

Comment: Its having enough data if u see the first table the headers are shrinked within same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for the above problem.

Corrected by modifying the CSS as below

So I have added `white-space : nowrap` hence the content looks good now with scroll bar with same data without shrinking

```
 .wrapper {
         overflow : auto;
         width: 1350px;
         white-space: nowrap;
         padding-bottom : 10px;
         padding-top : 10px;
    }

    .th {
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width : auto;
        height : word-spacing;
    white-space: nowrap;

    }

    .td {
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-style: solid;
        border-right-color: #ff0000;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Are the tables on the same page? If yes, change the table class to something else:

```
<table class="professional"> for table 1
<table class="professional2"> for table 2
```

And CSS for table 1:

```css
.professional .title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional .tableheader, .professional .pt-footer {
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional .tableheader:after {
    border-top-color: #2980b9;
}

.professional .pt-footer:after {
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

CSS for table 2:

```css
.professional2 .title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional2 .tableheader, .professional .pt-footer {
    background: #2980b9;
}

.professional2 .tableheader:after {
    border-top-color: #2980b9;
}

.professional2 .pt-footer:after {
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Both are present in same HTML page, But we can have same class for multiple table right .